# Refering Image in User Control Library in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am creating a user control Library in windows phone. It has default images in it for background and icons. 
The code I am writing in my user control file is

```
 <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/dropDownArrow.png"/>
```

`/Assets/dropDownArrow.png` is refered to the location in the project where the usercontrol is being used.

But I want to store these images or any file in my user controller's .dll.

Can anyone help me in this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In VS's solution explorer right-click on your image, select `Properties` and here set Build `Content` to `Resource`. Image will be compiled into DLL.

Comment: Sorry, forget to add link. http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-working-with-images-content-vs-resource-build-action Here is how.

Answer (score 0):

For this, Use `DependencyProperty`. Set The `DependencyProperty` To `ImageSource`.
 and whereever you want to use this in code, make a function and pass values